# Switching hosts, Moving databases, but having trouble

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, hosting, file-moving

So I do mainly design-based work for a small company. Graphic/Web (more so advertising). I have maintained and updated their decent-sized website for awhile now, but now we are switching hosts.

I have been asked for passwords to the wordpress blog databases, as they don't have them (neither do I). With that, I was asked to check the web configurations and look for database connection strings with the passwords. If not we'll have to reset them. I can setup wordpress blogs, write HTML, CSS and overall design - but databases and backend stuff is not my forte.

Can someone give me an idea of what it is I should be looking for, and where?

Comment: Wordpress Database doesn't need password. MySQL has Password and you can get it from the **wp-config.php** file by searching `define( 'DB_PASSWORD','YourPassword')`.Search for `DB_PASSWORD`.

Comment: Thank you. What would the database connection strings be?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you. Are you talking about the stuff that we do in `PHP` ?

Comment: I believe so. I am looking for passwords to website databases and have been asked if any are in the web configurations and what the database connection strings are with those passwords. I'm kind of out of touch with that stuff as I am primarily design and layout, whereas we outsource most backend and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should find your database password in the WordPress configuration file, wp-config.php.  This is usually located in the root of the site but it may have been moved outside the web root.

Answer (score 0):

Can you gain access to the FTP? Assuming so, look for a file on the main area where you have wordpress called wp-config.php. You'll be able to find your db connection stuff in there.